# How to use @EventListeners with Kafka poll() method?

Tags: java, events, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

There will be an event coming from kafka from some other applications and I want to listen to that event using spring events. The events are transported via kafka but How can I listen to that event?

```
`class Event{
String name;
int id;

}
`
```

The event transported would be of the type Event class, but how can I use poll which is to be used for kafka events?

Example :
`@EventListener public void handleEvent(){ <KafkaEvent>.poll() }` 
I couldn't understand how should I proceed with calling poll inside @EventListener method

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is spring-boot extension for Kafka, and [@KafkaListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation) annotation. You should rather use a `@KafkaListener` annotation instead of `@EventListener` for handling events from Kafka. It is simple, stable, and the preferred solution.

However, if you still want to use `@EventListener` you can inject `ApplicationEventPublisher` into the class responsible for polling messages from Kafka (eg. via `@KafkaListener`), example code below, but it is overengineering, introducing a lot of unnecessary complexity.

Possible, but **not the recommended** solution:

```java
@Component
class SomeKafkaHandler{

@Autowired
ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

@KafkaListener
void handleEvent(Event event){
   //forward to @EventListener
   eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
  }
}
```